# The method I am trying to call is not returning a value

Tags: java, methods, symbols

I'm trying to assign the return of a method to an int, but it's giving me an error "cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable columnResult"

Here is the code:

```
public void start() {
    String inputString = "XOXOXOO     X     XXO         X     OXO   ";


    columnResult();
    int column = columnResult;

    enterToken("X", inputString,column);    

  }
  private int columnResult(){
    System.out.println("Enter column for X:");
    String keyInput = Keyboard.readInput();
    int column1 = Integer.parseInt(keyInput);
    return column1;
  }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's returning a value just fine, but you're ignoring it. You need to assign it to column first: `column = columnResult()`. Get rid of the columnResult variable as that's just confusing you.

Comment: When you call a non-void method, e.g., `columnResult()`, you need to assign/save its return value to a variable, as suggested by @HovercraftFullOfEels, or else its value will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
int column = columnResult();
```

instead of 
    columnResult();
    int column = columnResult;

You must assign the result of the function right to the integer.

Answer (score 2):

you should directly write

```
int column = columnResult();
```

Since it is a method which returns an int

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
int column = columnResult();

not 

int column = columnResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
columnResult();
int column = columnResult;
```

should be

```
int column = columnResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to -

```
int column = columnResult();
```

By just calling `columnResult();` and not assigning the returned value you are loosing it.